# Error on uploading file and update the data through Ajax and Bootstarp Modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am newbie on Ajax and Bootstrap model. I follow this tutorial [Webslesson Tutorial](http://www.webslesson.info/2016/10/php-ajax-update-mysql-data-through-bootstrap-modal.html). But, I got some problem on uploading the file and updating the data. Please give some idea. 
Error:

1. While inserting the data,  Undefined index: image
2. Do not retrieve the data on the form while edit button click

**newsandnotice.php**

```
    <?php
if (isset($_GET['delmessage'])) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    alert("' . $_GET['delmessage'] . '");
    </script>';
} else if (isset($_GET['editmessage'])) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    alert("' . $_GET['editmessage'] . '");
    </script>';
}
//load the classes
require_once("../classes/connection.class.php");
require_once("../classes/notice.class.php");
$objNotice = new Notice();
$objNotice->getNotice();
?> 
<ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">
                                    <?php 
                                    if(isset($_GET['action']))
                                    {    
                                        if($_GET['action'] == "newsAndNotice"){
                                            echo "News And Notice";
                                            }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                            </li>
</ol>

<p>

</p>
<h2>Recent Notice and News View</h2> 

<div class="table-responsive">  
                    <div align="left">  

                            <button type="button" name="add" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-warning">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Add</span>
                            </button>  
                    </div>  
                <br />
    <div id="notice_table"> 
        <table class="table">  
            <tr>
                <th>S.N</th>
                <th>Notice Topic</th>
                <th>Notice Description</th>
                <th>Notice Date</th>
                <th>Picture</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $t=1;
                        if (sizeof($objNotice->data) > 0) {
                            foreach ($objNotice->data as $key => $value) {
                                ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php  echo $t++;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value['noticeTitle'];?></td>
                <td width="400"><?php echo substr($value['noticeDesc'],0,500)?>....</td>
                <td><?php echo $value['noticeDate'];?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php if($value['noticePicture']!="-" || $value['noticePicture']==""){?> <img src="image/notice/<?php echo $value['noticePicture'];?>" width="50px" height="50px"/> 
                    <?php }else{ echo"No image Availbale";}?>
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <a href="#" name="edit" value="Edit" id="<?php echo $value["noticeId"]; ?>" class="edit_data">  
                        <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
                    </a> ||
                    <a href="#" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo $value["noticeId"]; ?>" class="view_data" >
                        <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
              <?php
                }
              }
              ?>
        </table>
   </div>
</div>

 <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">News And Notice Details</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="noticeAndNews_detail">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div> 

 <div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Add & Update News And Notice</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                    <form method="post" id="insert_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                            <label>News Title: </label>  
                            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" />  
                              <br />  
                            <label>News Description: </label>  
                            <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control" required=""></textarea>  
                              <br />  
                              <br />  
                            <label>Date: </label>  
                            <input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="form-control" required=""/>  
                              <br />  
                            <label>Picture: </label>  
                            <input type="file" name="image" id="image" accept="image/*" class="form-control" />  
                              <br />  
                            <input type="hidden" name="noticeId" id="noticeId" />  
                            <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />
                    </form>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           $('#insert').val("Insert");  
           $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
           var noticeId = $(this).attr("id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"views/fetch/fetchNewsAndNotice.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{noticeId:noticeId},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#title').val(data.noticeTitle);  
                     $('#description').val(data.noticeDesc);  
                     $('#date').val(data.noticeDate);  
                     $('#image').val(data.noticePicture);  
                     $('#noticeId').val(data.noticeId);  
                     $('#insert').val("Update");  
                     $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');  
                }  
           });  
      });  
      $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
           event.preventDefault();  
           if($('#title').val() == "")  
           {  
                alert("title is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#description').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("description is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#date').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("date is required");  
           }    
           else  
           {  
                 $.ajax({  
                     url:"../processes/addnotice.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),  
                     beforeSend:function(){  
                          $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
                     },  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
                          $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');  
                          $('#notice_table').html(data);  
                     }  
                });   
           }  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){  
           var noticeId = $(this).attr("id");  
           if(noticeId != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"views/select/selectNoticeAndNews.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{noticeId:noticeId},  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#noticeAndNews_detail').html(data);  
                          $('#dataModal').modal('show');  
                     }  
                });  
           }            
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

**fetchNewsAndNotice.php**

```
<?php 
require_once("../../../classes/connection.class.php");
require_once("../../../classes/notice.class.php");

 if(isset($_POST["noticeId"]))  
 {  
    $objNotice = new Notice();
    $objNotice->setNoticeId($_POST["noticeId"]);
    $objNotice->getNotice();

    echo json_encode($objNotice->data);    
 }  
 ?>
```

**addNotice.php**

```
<?php
//load the classes
ob_start();
require_once("../classes/connection.class.php");
require_once("../classes/notice.class.php");
$objNotice = new Notice();

if(!empty($_POST)) {
$output = ''; 
$message = '';   
$noticeTitle=$_POST['title'];
$noticeDate=$_POST['date'];
$noticeDesc= mysqli_real_escape_string(Connection::$conxn,$_POST['description']);
$objNotice->setNoticeTitle($noticeTitle);
$objNotice->setNoticeDate($noticeDate);
$objNotice->setNoticeDesc($noticeDesc);

//change part start
if($_POST["noticeId"] != '')  
    {  
        $noticeId = $_POST['noticeId'];
        $objNotice->setNoticeId($noticeId);
           if( $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0){
                $objNotice->setPicture($image);
                $flag = $objNotice->editUploadOnServer('image', '../adminview/image/notice/');
            }else 
            {
                $objNotice->setPicture($image);
                $flag = $objNotice->updateNotice();
            }  
           $message = 'Data Updated';  
    }
else{

                    if($_FILES['image']['size'] > 0)
                    {
                        $flag = $objNotice->uploadOnServer('image', '../adminview/image/notice/');
                    }
                else 
                {
                    $image = "-";
                    $objNotice->setPicture($image);
                    $flag = $objNotice->addNotice();
                }
                $message = 'Data Inserted';  
} 
//change part end
if($flag){
    $output .= '<label class="text-success">' . $message . '</label>';   
    $output .= '  
     <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>S.N</th>
                <th>Notice Topic</th>
                <th>Notice Description</th>
                <th>Notice Date</th>
                <th>Picture</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>>';  

                $t=1;
                $objNoticeGet = new Notice();
                $objNoticeGet->getNotice();

            if (sizeof($objNoticeGet->data) > 0) 
                {
                    foreach ($objNoticeGet->data as $key => $value) 
                        {

        $output .= '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$t++.'</td>
                <td>'.$value['noticeTitle'].'</td>
                <td width="400">'.substr($value['noticeDesc'],0,500).'....</td>
                <td>'.$value['noticeDate'].'</td>
                <td><img src="image/notice/'.$value['noticePicture'].'" width="50px" height="50px"/></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" name="edit" value="Edit" id="'.$value["noticeId"] .'" class="edit_data">
                        <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
                    </a> ||
                    <a href="#" name="view" value="view" id="' . $value["noticeId"] . '" class="view_data" >
                        <span class="fa fa-eye"></span> 
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>';
                        }
                }
      $output.='</table>';  

    }
    echo $output;
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, I'd try to figure out what error you're getting.  Try adding an error handler to your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('ERROR: status='+xhr.status+", textStatus="+textStatus+", errorThrown="+errorThrown);
  },
 });
```

You can also use the console log to see what you're sending, before the ajax call:

```
console.log("Sending "+$('#insert_form').serialize());
```